# Google Search Console property not visible to delegated owner

Tags: google-search-console

I have a property A owned by Owner1 who delegates ownership to Owner2.

But that property is not visible to Owner2 on his webmaster console. Though Owner1 continues to see Owner2 as a verified owner (verified by delegation.)

What can be the issue? How can this be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just had the same issue. The solution is to click "Add A Property" in the Webmaster Tools Search Console page. Even though someone else assigned you as an owner, you still have to add the property and type in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This had been baffling us, but this worked perfectly:

1. Went to the console
2. Clicked "Add property"
3. Typed in domain `https://example.com`
4. It showed up immediately

Comment: I am not being critical. I know you have the best of intentions! What you state is interesting. But how does that answer or relate to the question? It confuses me. Can you clarify so that others understand? Again, I am sure you are well intended. I just don't get it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue, and the property was showing in Owner2 Webmasters Tools as well.

When in the Search Console under Owner2, click Add property on the top left, and you will see the same screen as for adding it for the first time (two options for domain or URL verification), which scared me off in the beginning. But once you type the domain name and click the button, it will say "Ownership Verified", and that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well. Fixed it by adding Owner 2 as a Full user first, then add as an Owner.

Start over..
1) Remove Owner 2 from being an owner. 
2) Add Owner 2 email as Full User
3) Add Owner 2 email as Owner