# Newly verified property is not showing up in Webmaster Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, search-engines, site-verification

### UPDATE: (2018-04-23) - *While revising this post to add more detail I went through the steps to add a property again. However, this time I googled "Google Webmaster Tools" and then used the link in search (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home). Voila -- It worked this time! As per posting best practices, I've added the pertinent details in an "answer" below for the benefit of those who may have a similar issue.*

When I wrote the post I used a link from a post on a website somewhere, which looked exactly the same as the link I used with success today, though it failed previously.

### THE ISSUE

I'm not really a newbie, but this might be a newbie question. I just verified a property (website) I own in Google Search Console (now part of "Google Webmaster Tools" suite). However, the property doesn't show up for some reason.

By verified I mean I added the property to my website, verified it (by uploading a .html file that began with "Google", followed by an alphanumeric sequence), then clicked the "Add A Property" button.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm stumped.

### SCREENSHOTS

**Add A Property button:**

[image]

**Property successfully added:**

[image]

### WHAT I'VE TRIED ALREADY THAT HASN'T WORKED

The only post I found that seemed like it might hold the answer was not applicable. It addresses a specific case of ownership transferral, which has nothing to do with my situation: [Google Search Console property not visible to delegated owner](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95068/google-search-console-property-not-visible-to-delegated-owner)

### QUESTIONS:

1. Why is my website not showing up in Google Search Console?
2. How can I get my website to show up in Google Search Console?

Any help is appreciated.

### MY QUESTIONS

1. Why is my counter not incrementing, but instead returning 'NaN'?
2. Is there some special way to declare an object property as a number before assigning a value?
3. What am I missing in my understanding to make this work? How can I increment my object count properties?

Any help is appreciated.

(P.S.: *Ive done my best to be thorough, but concise. Please let me know if anything needs clarification and please leave a comment if you downvote this for any reason so I can know why. Thanks in advance.*)

Comment: Are you saying you added the property for your website, verified it, and afterwards it's not listed in Google Search Console? If so, are you sure you're logged into the same Google account (it's possible to have more than one)? Have you tried logging in and out of that account, or using another browser?

Comment: Which verification method did you use?

Comment: Where is this website not showing up?  Is it not listed on the home page of search console?  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en   Is it not listed in the site switcher drop down menu from another Search Console property?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller & Dan: Thanks for your comments. I will update my question to reflect the answers.

Comment: Same happening to me - domain verified (several days ago ) and appearing in the 'new look' console - but not appearing in the 'original' console layout. This means I am unable to access disavow tool...as that appears only visible on old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While revising this post to add more detail I went through the steps to add a property again. However, this time I googled "Google Webmaster Tools" and then used the link in search (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home). Voila -- It worked this time!

### POSSIBLE REASONS IT WORKED THIS TIME

When I wrote the post I used a link from a post on a website somewhere, which seemed to work. For anyone else who may run into this problem I am documenting the 'solution' here:

1. I was using an old link. I suppose it is possible that even though the link I used last Friday led me to something that looks almost exactly like what I'm looking at today (Monday), that it could have been a mirror, or something, right?
2. Search console happened to broken or under-maintenance -- though no one saw fit to post a notice for the puplic. I learned today (because Google told me in a message) that Google Search Console has NEW BETA here:

   https://search.google.com/search-console?utm_source=wmx&utm_medium=navigation-panel&resource_id=http://erichepperle.com/

This might indicate that the "under-construction" hypthesis is likely.

1. I was tired and wasn't able to complete instructions correctly. While it is true that I was tired when attempting to add a property, it's not rocket science and I know what I experienced.

Your mileage may vary. And I hope my contribution to this particular challenge with newly verified google search console/webmaster tools properties (a possible quirk, that could still show up in the future) will help somebody else down the road, into the future.

*... as long as the admins don't delete it ... or the Community bot. ;)*

Comment: Glad it was something simple.   We won't delete this.  Thank you for posting a thorough answer.